# Connect laptop as second monitor for other laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, external-monitor

I have old laptop which I wanna connect to other one as second monitor. I saw few answers on similar questions here, but all of them seems to be outdated. So my question is how to do it in modern way. Should I connect laptops via LAN cable? Do I need to install additional software?

Comment: Please post the links to the outdated solutions that you already have examined.

Comment: You can't. At best you can setup some sort of remote desktop sharing but that isn't in any way a "second monitor", it mirrors the real monitor.